# How to put best meta for Blogspot?

Tags: blogspot

I face big problem with my Blogger template, and I need your help to correct it.

This is code meta tag. Please check it, because the recent posts do not show in Google Archive.

```html
<!-- All in One SEO Pack for blogger by arabes1.com -->
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    <meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
    <link href='http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g' rel='openid.server'/>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' rel='openid.delegate'/>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;error_page&quot;'>
    <title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
    </b:if></b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
    <title>Page Not Found - <data:blog.title/></title>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
    <meta content='noindex' name='robots'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
    <meta content='noindex,nofollow' name='robots'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
    <meta content='noindex,nofollow' name='robots'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;error_page&quot;'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl != data:blog.url'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName + &quot;, &quot; + data:blog.pageTitle + &quot;, &quot; + data:blog.title' name='keywords'/>
    </b:if></b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <meta content='download, cutter, free, MP3 Cutter, change ip, video player, betternet,bramj, موقع برامج نت ,hola, learn english, translator, twitter, تحميل مجاني, تغيير الاي بي, موقع برامج' name='keywords'/></b:if>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - Atom&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/atom+xml'/>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - RSS&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml'/>
    <link expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/feeds/&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;/posts/default&quot;' expr:title='data:blog.title + &quot; - Atom&quot;' rel='alternate' type='application/atom+xml'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
    <link expr:href='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' rel='image_src'/>
    </b:if></b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.url' property='og:url'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageName'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta content='website' property='og:type'/></b:if></b:if></b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
    <b:else/></b:if>
    <link href='https://www.blogger.com/favicon-image.g?blogID=6444158710562232230' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <meta content='state, Country' name='geo.placename'/>
    <meta content='محمد زوكربيرج ' name='Author'/>
    <meta content='general' name='rating'/>
    <meta content='Palestine' name='geo.country'/>
    <meta content='ar_AR' property='og:locale'/>
    <meta content='ar_AR' property='og:locale:alternate'/>
    <meta content='Arabic' name='language'/>

 <!-- META plus.google --> 
 <link href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/+%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9/posts' rel='publisher'/>
    <link href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/+%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9/about' rel='author'/>
    <link href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/+%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9' rel='me'/>
 
 <!-- META verification --> 
 <meta content='p67NQao-e0xkW0RKe2DhhNMHSAx1nGDHc0PagqegBM0' name='google-site-verification'/>
    <meta content='732391813E26EC08E5F9828D239FCD58' name='msvalidate.01'/>
    <meta content='orifhUgfGzV6J6OTwg8Qp4QqMjw' name='alexaVerifyID'/>
 
 <!-- business:contact --> 
 <meta content='Palestine' property='business:contact_data:locality'/>
    <meta content='00972' property='business:contact_data:postal_code'/>
    <meta content='Palestine' property='business:contact_data:country_name'/>
    <meta content='mohammed.zuck7@gmail.com' property='business:contact_data:email'/>
    <meta content='https://www.ar-download.info/p/' property='business:contact_data:website'/>
 
 <!-- Open Graph --> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='203255686429440' property='fb:page_id'/>
<meta content='FACEBOOK-APP-ID' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='100025021673219' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;index&quot;,&quot;archive&quot;}'>
  <meta content='website' property='og:type'/>
  <meta content='' property='og:image'/>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;item&quot;,&quot;static_page&quot;}'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image:alt'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100025021673219' property='article:author'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/bramjnet.website' property='article:publisher'/>
</b:if>
 
 <!-- Twitter Card --> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='twitter:domain'/>
<meta content='summary_large_image' name='twitter:card'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription ? data:blog.metaDescription : data:blog.pageName' name='twitter:description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' name='twitter:image'/> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName ? data:blog.pageName : data:blog.pageTitle' name='twitter:title'/>
<meta content='@bramj11' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='@bramj11' name='twitter:creator'/>
<!-- DNS-PREFETCH --> 
<link href='//www.blogger.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//1.bp.blogspot.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//2.bp.blogspot.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//3.bp.blogspot.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//4.bp.blogspot.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//28.2bp.blogspot.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//resources.blogblog.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//www.facebook.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//plus.google.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//twitter.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//www.youtube.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//feedburner.google.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//feeds.feedburner.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//apis.google.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//connect.facebook.net' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//www.google-analytics.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//googleads.g.doubleclick.net' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//www.gstatic.com' rel='preconnect'/>
<link href='//www.googletagservices.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//static.xx.fbcdn.net' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
<link href='//tpc.googlesyndication.com' rel='dns-prefetch'/>
    <!-- End of All in One SEO Pack for blogger by arabes1.com -->
```

Comment: It looks like an editor removed the link to your website from this question. This is generally a good thing, since we want questions to be self-contained here, and have educational value for many years. Links to websites will no longer demonstrate the problem you have once you have fixed it, so we discourage them.

Comment: why did he delete the links !!

Comment: I have explained that in my comment above. If I was not clear enough, would you explain what part you don't understand?